# How to fetch data from the relations of table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations, apiato

i have three models called review,charge and card.in controller review model is being used so based on that model i want to fetch card model data(in this case it's name), can you please help me to achieve this thing..

I am using APIATO framework for developing APIS ,in that i have one array `fieldSearchable`(Ref:- http://apiato.io/docs/9.x/core-features/search-query-parameter/) which is responsible for searching there i want to use `cardCharge.name` to fetch the name of a cards table but it's not working please help me to achieve this thing

Comment: What have you tried on controller? Post your controller code

Comment: it seems both card and charge have each other's id in their tables! Anyway, have you tried like $review->charge->card_used?

Comment: Besides, it is best if you use nested eager loading in these cases, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

Comment: please share what you have tried and what output you get so far.